# Fourier data with non-integer periods, correcting for phase bias

Tags: curve-fitting

I have data that I believe is sinusoidal, but I don't have an integral 
number of periods. How do I find the "best fit" `Sin/Cos` function, 
compensating for this and for the ugly constant that appears? EXAMPLE:

- Here is some data that follows a sinusoidal pattern (Mathematica format)

  `t4 = N[Table[Sin[3.17*2*Pi*x/200], {x,1,200}]];`
- Now, using just `t4`, I want to get back `Sin[3.17*2*Pi*x/200]` or the 
  equivalent.
- Note that `Mean[t4]` is non-zero (it's about `0.0281886`). The 
  analyses I've tried so far "pull out" this mean (like "`0.0281886 + ...`"). 
  This is bad because it's unlikely I'll get back to my original form 
  with that constant pulled out.
- Using j0ker5's excellent technique from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463481/continuous-fourier-transform-on-discrete-data-using-mathematica I can compensate for the non-integral period and get:

  `0.0281886 + 0.983639 Cos[1.49867 - 0.0992743 x]`

Note that the `x` term is `3.16*2*Pi*x/200`, very close to my original.

- I modified j0ker5's technique slightly. The actual function I used 
  to get the above:

`superfourier2[data_] :=Module[ 
 {pdata, n, f, pos, fr, frpos, freq, phase, coeff}, 
 pdata = data; 
 n = Length[data]; 
 f = Abs[Fourier[pdata]]; 
 pos = Ordering[-f, 1][[1]] - 1; 
 fr = Abs[Fourier[pdata*Exp[2*PiIposRange[0,n-1]/n], 
      FourierParameters -> {0, 2/n}]]; 
 frpos = Ordering[-fr, 1][[1]]; 
 freq = (pos + 2(frpos - 1)/n); 
 phase = Sum[Exp[freq*2*PiIx/n]*pdata[[x]], {x,1,n}]; 
 coeff =  N[{Mean[data], 2*Abs[phase]/n, freq*2*Pi/n, Arg[phase]}]; 
 Function[x, Evaluate[coeff[[1]] + coeff[[2]]*Cos[coeff[[3]]*x - coeff[[4]]]]] 
]`

- In addition to the bad constant term, note that adding
  "`0.983639*Cos[1.49867 - 0.0992743 x]`" for `x=1..200` yields `0.0279175*200`,
  which I'm convinced makes things worse, not better.
- I believe the `0.0279175*200` sum from the cosine and the 
  `200*0.0281886` from the mean can somehow "cancel" to yield back my 
  pure `Sin[]` function.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [periodogram](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16117/what-method-can-be-used-to-detect-seasonality-in-data/16169#16169) will estimate the periods.  It will also handle noisy data and pick out multiple sinusoidal components of different period.

A quick and dirty *Mathematica* calculation is

```
data = N[Table[Sin[3.17*2*Pi*x/200], {x, 1, n}]];
welch = 1 - (2 (Range[n] - (n - 1)/2)/(n + 1))^2;
fData = Append[Abs[Fourier[welch data]]^2 / (Plus @@ (welch^2)), 0];
fData = (fData + Reverse[fData])/2;
fData = fData / (Plus @@ fData);
```

(You don't really need the last two steps, but I kept them in because they produced the illustrations below.)

Here's a plot of the important part of the periodogram in this example:

[image: Periodogram]

The points are the periodogram values while the line is a quick smooth (I used a polynomial interpolator of order 5, but with more time would apply a Gaussian kernel smooth):

```
f = Interpolation[Log[fData], InterpolationOrder -> 5];
period = x /. (NMaximize[f[x + 1], x] // Last)
```

The maximum of the smoothed value occurs at $3.17661$, whose closeness to $3.17$ is evidence of the promise of this technique.

Once you have an estimate of the period, it's straightforward to find the phase and amplitude (use nonlinear least squares, or run a tight bandpass filter over the Fourier transform and invert it).

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, a Sin[\[Phi] + period*2*Pi*x/200], {a, \[Phi]}, x]
```

The estimated amplitude ($a$) is $1.00011$ and phase ($\phi$) is $0.0212758$, both close to the actual values of $1$ and $0$, respectively.  (The phase estimate is less than one sampling interval ($2\pi/200 = 0.0314$) from the correct phase, which is about as good as one can expect.)  Compare the data to this fit:

[image: Data and fit]

The residuals exhibit some quasi-periodicity (attributable to cutting off the data at a non-integral period) and range from $-0.018$ to $0.021$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the purpose of the `welch = ...` part?

Comment: @Szabolcs: It helps to smooth the data before computing their Fourier Transform.  The Welch method, which is a running weighted average (with weights that linearly decrease with distance) is described in *Numerical Recipes*.