# Detecting the period of a signal with a length of only a few periods

Tags: time-series, signal-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fourier data with non-integer periods, correcting for phase bias](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16230/fourier-data-with-non-integer-periods-correcting-for-phase-bias)

I have a not perfectly but quit periodic signal, with a length of only a few periods.  What methods are available for automatically measuring its period?

I tried using the maximum of the Fourier transform, but this essentially only tells me how many integer periods are there in the full length of the signal.  If I only have a few repetitions, this will give me an inaccurate estimate of the period.

Let me illustrate: suppose we have a perfectly periodic function $sin(x)$ sampled at intervals of 0.01 between 0 and 30.  The Fourier transform will tell me that the signal is about 5 periods long, which gives an inaccurate period length of 30/5 = 6, instead of the true one which is $2\pi \approx 6.28$.  Since this example signal is almost perfectly periodic and sampled at a high density, it is possible to do much better than this.

**What robust ways are there for period detection that might work in this scenario?**

**EDIT:**  [Here](http://ge.tt/8Lt9S8B?c) is an example signal of 1000 sample points to test on. I am expecting a period of around ~150, by manual measurement (i.e. 6 repetitions in a length of ~898). You may argue that it should be double that value if you look closely at the alternating height of the small humps, but as the signal is not *perfectly* periodic, for this application I need ~150.

Comment: Fast'n' dirty idea is to supersample the data with a spline or smoothing and run DFT on this to get "denser" spectrum.

Comment: @mbq But the problem actually isn't the sampling rate.  In my $sin(x)$ example above, DFT will always tell me that I have 5 repetitions, regardless of how dense the sampling is.  Simply because it will always give an integer number of repetitions.

Comment: Per @SEngstrom's [answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4464817/492043), looking at the autocorrelation function seems a simple way to do this. For your example data, the first maximum away from zero occurs around a lag of 76, with a bigger maximum around 149.

Comment: @onestop That is actually what I am using now, or something similar.  The messy part is trying to pick out the correct peaks.