# Irregular seasonality defined as white noise?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, prediction, seasonality

I've got data of which I think it has a seasonality. My data has a peak in july/august and one in december. I have only data of 2014 and 2015, but in both of the cases this is happening. (See my graph)

I tried to confirm this with autocorrelation, but this method only gives the so-called "White noise", probably because the seasons are 'irregular' (not one peak per year or something, it's not yearly, not quarterly etc.)

I need to forecast over this data, but I'm not sure if I should pick a model that uses seasonality or one that doesn't use seasonality.

[image: Data]

[image]

Comment: You can find this thread about detecting seasonality helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16117/what-method-can-be-used-to-detect-seasonality-in-data

Comment: There's nothing that can be done with seasonality if you have data for only one cycle. Unless, of course you have a very good theory behind the data.

Comment: @Aksakal I've got two cycles, 2014 and 2015, right?

Comment: Ok, two cycles is better than one :) Just put the dummy variable on "summer" months.

Comment: @Aksakal Even when my autocorrelation doesn't show seasonality? Do you maybe have an example of a model with a dummy variable? Or could I just add it with a certain parameter to any model?

Comment: @Tim I see now I shouldn't use autocorrelation with irregular seasonality, are there other methods except autocorrelation I can use to determine seasonality? I have only 24 data points of 24 months so I don't think the power plot of the link you posted is usable for me