# Detecting seasonality from periodogram and seasonplots

Tags: r, seasonality, spectral-analysis, multiple-seasonalities

I want to determine whether a time series contains seasonality, and if so, what the periodicity is so I can include this as Fourier terms in my model.
Because I have to do this for approximately 100 different univariate series  and don't want to inspect them all intensively, I use the `tbats()` function to check if the result contains seasonal component.

For the series that contained a seasonal component, I looked at the power spectrum of the differenced data to determine the periodicity as suggested by whuber♦ in[What method can be used to detect seasonality in data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16117/what-method-can-be-used-to-detect-seasonality-in-data).

For one of the ts consisting of **weekly data** for a period of two years the spectrum plot produced by `spectrum(diff(ts), log = "no", span = c(3, 5))` of the *differenced* data looks as follows:
[image: Periodogram differenced data]

I am having a hard time figuring out what the periodicity of this series is, i.e. how to read this plot. At what level on the spectrum is a peak considered high enough to include it as a seasonal component? The function `findfrequency()` returns a frequency of 3.

I didn't get much wiser from the seasonplot on the differenced data either.
[image]

The `stl()` decomposotion shows yearly seasonality.
[image]

The ACF and PACF of the non-differenced data. 
[image: ACF and PACF]

ACF has peaks at lags higher than 52/53 weeks.

Comment: Have you tried using `stl()` and `acf()` / `pacf()`?

Comment: Yes, but they give contradicting results. `stl()` returns yearly seasonality, while `acf()` on differenced ts show peaks at lags 30 and 31.

Comment: Include all these plots in the qeustion (on the original non-differenced time series!).

Comment: Your periodogram looks wrong - it shows a "frequency" axis with values from 0-25, which substantially exceeds the [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency).  Are you sure this axis isn't showing the *period* (i.e., *inverse* of the frequency)?

Comment: I used the  `spectrum()` function from [stats v3.5.1][1] package which takes `(-frequency(x)/2, +frequency(x)/2]` as the range on the x-axis. Since it is a weekly ts, 0-25 makes sense, but I'm not sure about the interpretation. 
[1]:https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/spectrum