# How to find whether the time series is seasonal and to find the period of seasonality if seasonal?

Tags: time-series, python, data-visualization, autocorrelation, seasonality

I need to find my time series data whether it is seasonal or not.

My actual time series plot is shown below, The data is of irregular hourly data from January 1st of 2018 to August 1st of 2018.

[image]

Then I resampled it as daily time series data then the plot looked like,

[image]

Upon seeing the above plot also I am not sure whether it contains seasonal component.

Then I tried checking with stl decomposition with period as 30 for monthly seasonality,

[image]

Then I tried with ACF plot to check the seasonality again for 50 lags,

[image]

Based on above observations, I am still not able to find that my time series data contain seasonal component in it. Assist me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16117/what-method-can-be-used-to-detect-seasonality-in-data ?