# Statistical tests for periodicity in a histogram

Tags: hypothesis-testing, count-data, circular-statistics

I am trying to analyse the distribution of pairwise distances between data points distributed on a circle. In particular, I am interested in determining  whether there is any periodicity in these data.

For example, in the histogram shown below I would like to test whether there is an increase in the frequency of data at pairwise distances that are multiples of 60 degrees (or alternatively at multiples of 90 degrees or 45 degrees etc). Are there any established ways of testing this?

I thought of fitting a simple linear model with sinusoidal regressors and then cross-validating fit quality. However the only way I can think of leaving out data is by leaving out bins and this entire approach seems intuitively unappealing.

Obviously this analysis is further complicated by the fact that pairwise distances tend to be small.

[image]

Comment: Plot the magnitude of the Fourier transform of the data.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16117 and search our site for threads about "seasonality."

Comment: that works thank you! :)