# Looking for Pattern in Daily Data in Time Series

Tags: r, time-series

I have a sample data here for a daily time series and I want to how can I find out if it shows a weekly or 10 day pattern.

```
sampledata<- rnorm(200, mean = 10, sd = 23)

ts_df <- ts( sampledata, frequency=1, start=as.Date("2012-03-07"))
plot(ts_df )
```

Comment: If you expect the pattern to appear in the conditional mean of the series, then look at autocorrelations and partial autocorrelations at lags 7 and 10. For that you may use functions `acf` and `pacf`.

Comment: @Richard Hardy, thanks but do I have to used differences before I used acf and pact?

Comment: If your data is stationary, do not difference before running `acf` and `pacf`. If your data is integrated of order 1, difference first.

Comment: @RichardHardy is there any way I can determine the pattern without looking at the acf graph. Maybe I can create a test to know if it display a 7 or 10 day pattern. I have hundreds of data and its hard if I look at the plots one at a time. Thank you.

Comment: I think I can modify Rob Hyndman answer here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57705/identify-seasonality-in-time-series-data so it can tell me whether I have a 7 day or 10 day seasonality