# How to determine Forecastability of time series?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, entropy, maximum-entropy, forecastability

One of the important issues being faced by forecasters is if the given series  **can** be forecasted or not ?

I stumbled on an article entitled "[Entropy as an A Priori Indicator of Forecastability](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/268804262_Entropy_as_an_A_Priori_Indicator_of_Forecastability)" by Peter Catt that uses [Approximate Entropy (ApEn)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_entropy)  as a relative measure to determine of a given time series is forecastable.

The article says,

> "Smaller ApEn values indicate a greater chance that a set of data will
>   be followed by similar data (regularity). Conversely, a larger value
>   of ApEn indicates a lower chance of similar data being repeated
>   (irregularity). Hence, larger values convey more disorder, randomness
>   and system complexity."

And is followed by mathematical formulas for calculating ApEn. This is an interesting approach because it provides a numerical value that can be used to assess forecastablity in relative sense. I don't know what Approximate Entropy means, I'm reading more about it.

There is a package called [pracma](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/index.html) in `R` that lets you calculate ApEn. For an illustrative purpose, I used 3 different time series and calculated the ApEn numbers.

1. **Series 1:** The famous AirPassenger time series -  is highly deterministic and we should be able to forecast easily.
2. **Series 2:** Sunspot Time Series - is very well defined but should be less forecastable than series 1.
3. **Series 3:** Random Number There is no way to forecast this series.

So if we calculate ApEn, Series 1 should be less than Series 2 should be very very less Series 3.

Below is the R snippet that calculates ApEn for all the three series.

```
library("pracma")
> series1 <- approx_entropy(AirPassengers)
> series1
[1] 0.5157758
> series2 <- approx_entropy(sunspot.year)
> series2
[1] 0.762243
> series3 <- approx_entropy(rnorm(1:30))
> series3
[1] 0.1529609
```

This is not what I expected. The random series has a lower number than the well defined AirPassenger series.   Even if I increase the random number to 100, I still get the following which is less than the well defined series 2/Sunspot.yealry series.

```
> series3 <- approx_entropy(rnorm(1:100))
> series3
[1] 0.747275
```

Below are my questions:

1. There are 2 parameters in calculating  ApEn (`m` and `r`) ? How to determine them. Iused defaults in the `R` code above.
2. What am I doing incorrectly that is showing that incorrectly that ApEn is lower for random numbers vs. a well defined series such as sunspot.yearly.
3. Should I deseasonalize/detrend the series and then estimate ApEn. The author however has applied ApEn directly to the series.
4. Is there any other way to determine if the series is forecastable ?

Comment: As stated in the article approximate entropy should not be used on short time series, N<200. More importantly, the article uses sample entropy not approximate entropy. Pracma contains both. Thanks

Comment: Does it account for explanatory variables? For instance, if you're forecasting account attrition of a firm, it may be correlated with marketing spending, and spending is highly forecastable, in fact, it's planned months ahead. How would this be accounted in the proposed approach?

Comment: @Aksakal, no there is no explanatory variables. I was looking for large scale univariate (no explanatory variable) time series forecasting where we need an objective measure to assess forecastability. Also, in many many instances, univariate forecasting is much more accurate than models built with explanotary variables.

Comment: Sure, univariate forecasting has its uses. It's just in my domain it's rarely useful. In my case it's either I have to forecast multiple correlated endogenous series, or my series are clearly correlated with exogenous factors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assessing forecastability of time series](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23007/assessing-forecastability-of-time-series)

Comment: My sense is that this is a much narrower question than the suggested duplicate. Voting leave open, but suggest the OP consider a more specific title to avoid confusing the two. Say, "How to determine forecastability of times series *using approximate entropy*?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parameters `m` and `r`, involved in calculation of *approximate entropy (ApEn)* of time series, are *window (sequence) length* and *tolerance (filter value)*, correspondingly. In fact, in terms of `m`, `r` as well as `N` (number of data points), *ApEn* is **defined** as "natural logarithm of the relative prevalence of repetitive patterns of length `m` as compared with those of length `m + 1`" (Balasis, Daglis, Anastasiadis & Eftaxias, 2011, p. 215):

$$ ApEn(m, r, N) = \Phi^m(r) - \Phi^{m+1}(r), $$

$\text{where }$

$$ \Phi^m(r) = {\LARGE{\Sigma}_i} lnC^m_i(r)/(N - m + 1) $$

Therefore, it appears that changing the tolerance `r` allows to control the (temporal) *granularity* of determining time series' entropy. Nevertheless, using the default values for both `m` and `r` parameters in `pracma` package's entropy function calls works fine. The only **fix** that needs to be done to see the *correct entropy values relation* for all three time series (lower entropy for more well-defined series, higher entropy for more random data) is to *increase the length of random data vector*:

```
 library(pracma)
 set.seed(10)
 all.series <- list(series1 = AirPassengers,
                    series2 = sunspot.year,
                    series3 = rnorm(500)) # <== size increased
 sapply(all.series, approx_entropy)
  series1   series2   series3 
  0.5157758 0.7622430 1.4741971
```

The results are as expected - as the predictability of fluctuations decreases from most determined `series1` to most random `series 3`, their entropy consequently increases: `ApEn(series1) < ApEn(series2) < ApEn(series3)`.

In regard to other **measures** of *forecastability*, you may want to check *mean absolute scaled errors (MASE)* - see [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23007/31372) for more details. *Forecastable component analysis* also seems to be an interesting and new **approach** to determining forecastability of time series. And, expectedly, there is an `R` package for that, as well - [**ForeCA**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ForeCA).

```
library(ForeCA)
sapply(all.series,
       Omega, spectrum.control = list(method = "wosa"))
 series1   series2   series3 
 41.239218 25.333105  1.171738
```

Here $\Omega \in [0, 1]$ is a measure of forecastability where $\Omega(white noise) = 0\%$ and $\Omega(sinusoid) = 100 \%$.

**References**

Balasis, G., Daglis, I. A., Anastasiadis, A., & Eftaxias, K. (2011). Detection of dynamical complexity changes in Dst time sSeries using entropy concepts and rescaled range analysis. In W. Liu and M. Fujimoto (Eds.), *The Dynamic Magnetosphere, IAGA Special Sopron Book, Series 3, 211.* doi:10.1007/978-94-007-0501-2_12. Springer. Retrieved from http://members.noa.gr/anastasi/papers/B29.pdf

Georg M. Goerg (2013): Forecastable Component Analysis. JMLR, W&CP (2) 2013: 64-72. http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/papers/goerg13

Comment: I also tested `pracma::sample_entropy()` function and the corrects results relation across the time series holds in that scenario as well.

Comment: @forecaster: You're welcome.

Comment: See also this paper https://notsoirrational.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/schulz15.pdf  which uses experimental data to justify their measures of predictability.  It also relates some of the work to the ForeCA work mentioned in this post

Comment: @GeorgM.Goerg: Thank you for the suggestions, link & edits.

Comment: @forecaster: My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Every time series is made up of 3 components: Trend, Seasonality, and Random. If the data exhibits a strong trend and or is highly seasonal, then prediction will be relatively easy. If the data is mostly random, then by definition you can't predict anything.