# Detecting peaks in noisy quasi-periodic time series

Tags: time-series, noise

I have the following acceleration data taken from my phone when rowing [image: acceleration time series]

The negative peak is the point at which the oars go in the water. I would like to be able to identify this peak in real time when rowing.

Given the data is roughly periodic - with frequency between 0.1 and 1 times per second - and has a characteristic shape. What would be the best way to detect these peaks in real time?

data here for anyone interested: [acceleration data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hrf4fPuA2wq205_XV9ZJK9D--HIJXf3r/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you be more specific about "in real time"?  Would that be milliseconds after each event, seconds, or maybe immediately after the workout?

Comment: By real time I mean at least within one period. So if frequency is 1/s than within 1s of the peak occurring.

Comment: Okay.  I see two kinds of troughs: the deeper ones preceding peaks and the shallower ones that follow peaks (after the oars have exited the water).  Which of these do you wish to detect?

Comment: The deeper ones before the peaks. I think what is happening is because the phone is not completely fixed to the shell of the boat, as the oars are removed, the phone rattles around a bit. I feel like we should be able to get rid of most of that noise with a low-pass filter.

Comment: I'm hoping that this peak detection can be achieved without too many tuning parameters, given we know a lot about how the signal should look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the simplest ways that is likely to work follows a "smooth, detect, check" workflow.

1. **Smooth** the data to suppress noise.  A running convolution with an extremely smooth kernel is a good idea because it will produce smooth derivatives, too.  I use a Gaussian.
2. **Detect** the troughs.  To do this reliably you want (a) the smoothed value to be relatively low and (b) to be genuinely in a trough rather than a local dip.  To this end, maintain (1) a smoothed version of the typical amplitude and (2) an estimate of the second derivative of the signal.
3. **Check** the results by looking around in a small temporal neighborhood of the apparent trough locations.  Often, a trough will result in a short burst of detections.  You may locate the trough with the first, the last, or the middle time in that burst if you like.

There are some parameters to tune.  The most important is the smoothing bandwidth: too small, and it will not reduce the noise and create spurious detections; too large, and the times of the troughs will be imprecise (and it will take too long to detect them: the time lapse needed for a kernel smooth equals its bandwidth).

Here is an automatically generated solution.

[image: Figure]

The faint gray trace is the original data; the black version is its smooth with a bandwidth of 64 ticks (about one-tenth of a cycle); the light blue plots the second derivative; and the red dots locate the estimated troughs.  Dashed red lines are drawn through those points to show how regularly they appear.

Some details at the beginning and end of the procedure show more clearly what is going on.

[image: Figure 2]

The estimated locations of the troughs look very accurate, especially once the amplitude reaches its quasi steady state after time 2000.

[image: Figure 3]

At the end, this procedure gracefully shuts down and does not detect spurious troughs.

I wrote this `R` code to emphasize the sequential nature of this detection process.  (It would be more efficient to collect the entire dataset and use the Fast Fourier Transform for the smoothing if you don't need real-time detection.)

```R
#
# Initialize an object to maintain information about a narrow time window.
# `W` is the most recent window of data while `A` holds their squared amplitudes
# (within, potentially, a window of different length).
#
initialize <- function(h) {
  k <- dnorm(seq(-2, 2, length.out = 2*h + 1)); k <- k / sum(k)
  u <- rep(1/h, h)
  list(i = -h, y = NA, a = NA, h = h, K = k, U = u, W = rep(NA, 0), A = rep(0, 0))
}
#
# Process the next datum, returning the updated object.
# The caller will use the update for trough detection.
#
update <- function(x, obj) {
  within(obj, {
    if (length(W) >= length(K)) W <- W[-1]
    if (length(A) >= length(U)) A <- A[-1]
    W <- c(W, x)
    A <- c(A, x^2)
    if (length(W) >= length(K)) y <- sum(K * W) else y <- NA
    if (length(A) >= length(U)) a <- sqrt(sum(U * A)) else a <- NA
    i <- i + 1
  })
}
#
# Read the sample data.
#
X <- read.csv("C:/Users/whube/Downloads/acceleration.txt", header = FALSE)$V1
# X <- X[(length(X) - 1e4 + 1):length(X)]
# X <- X[1:1e4]
n <- length(X)
#
# Process the data sequentially.
#
initialize(2^6) -> obj
Y <- matrix(rep(NA, 4*n), 4, dimnames = list(c("i", "y", "a", "trough"), NULL))
for (i in 1:n) {
  obj <- update(X[i], obj)
  
  # Detect troughs.  Store the updated values for later plotting.
  Y[, i] <- with(obj, {
    c(i, y, a, y <= -a/3 & a > 2)
    })
}
#
# Plot the results.
#
plot(obj$h:n, X[obj$h:n], type = "l", col = gray(0.75), 
     main = "End", family = "Informal",
     xlab = "Tick", ylab = "Values")
lines(seq_len(n) - obj$h, Y["y", ], col = "Black", lwd = 2)
lines(seq_len(n) - length(obj$U), Y["a",], col = "skyblue", lwd = 2)
#
# Plot the trough locations.
# This uses a little post-processing to merge short bursts of troughs into
# single time points.  This typically takes only a handful of ticks, 
# maintaining the real-time quality of the algorithm.
#
v <-  which(Y["trough", ]==1) - obj$h
j <- which(diff(c(v, Inf)) > 1)
abline(v = v[j-1], lty = 3, col = "Red")

z <- apply(rbind(v[j-1], v[j]), 2, function(k) min(X[k[1]:k[2]]))
k <- apply(rbind(v[j-1], v[j]), 2, function(k) which.min(Y["y", k[1]:k[2]]) + k[1]-1)
points(k, z, pch = 21, bg = "Red")
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like it works well! So you look back over the last ~64 data points. If the convolution of those points with a Gaussian is greater than one third of their standard deviation (in the negative), then you say you've detected a peak. Is there any advantage to this over using an exponential filter (e.g. y <- c(y, 0.1*x + 0.9*tail(y, n=1)))?

Comment: Also is there any way do you think of taking into account the periodicity of the data? I can think of naive ways, such as adding some hysteresis in trough detection (perhaps ignoring detected troughs within a certain number of ticks, or increasing the threshold for trough detection when a trough has been recently detected)

Comment: The exponential filter has the advantage of being more efficient to update, which is a good idea in this application.  I would suggest experimenting with it: it ought to work.  (2) I opted not to exploit the quasi-periodicity because (a) it leads to a more complicated algorithm and (b) I felt you could not rely on it: any slight break in the rhythm will force it to detect that it's failing, resort to some fall-back estimator, and then detect when the rhythm resumes.  If you have a need for *immediate* detection (lags of just a few milliseconds) then this would be the way to go.