# Fix wrong data coming from a sensor

Tags: outliers, data-preprocessing

I have data coming from a sensor that I store in a time serie.

When I graph them, I obtain:

[image: raw data chart]

These data are supposed to be "continuous", like temperatures, not going up and down so fast.

After searching similar issues on the web - I think "smoothen curve" have given me the more relevant results - I apply "convolution" to data, using code provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26337730/5763327).

I obtain:

[image: with convolution chart]

It is not satisfying as I guess that some data points are just "wrong" and should be removed, not averaged.

Doing it by hand is quite easy as we can guess the curve:

[image: by hand fixed chart]

Here are [the data](https://framabin.org/p/?bd6f2e1ce76279cd#jIkit9VsdHCgGba0vx0nbnyQTAcmIhbd5EVzlW8ozII=) and code to produce the second chart:

```
def smooth(y, box_pts):
    import numpy as np
    box = np.ones(box_pts)/box_pts
    return np.convolve(y, box, mode='same')


def load_data(f):
    from datetime import datetime as dt
    with open(f, "rt") as fd:
        X = []
        Y = []
        for line in fd.readlines():
            (x,y)=line.strip().split(" ")
            X.append(dt.fromtimestamp(int(x)))
            Y.append(float(y))
        return (X, Y)


import sys
(X,Y) = load_data(sys.argv[1])

from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show
plot(X, Y,'b-')
plot(X, smooth(Y,19), 'g-', lw=2)
show()
```

I'm looking for an algorithm that would remove "bad" values, any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried MA smoothing?

Comment: @user2974951, I don't know what is MA.

Comment: Moving Average, in the context of time series analysis.

Comment: If you don't want to average the "wrong" observations, you could try removing the culprits, and then using spline interpolation.

Comment: @user2974951, yes, I want to remove the culprits. The point is how to detect them automatically.

Comment: You can find some good ideas at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/simple-algorithm-for-online-outlier-detection-of-a-generic-time-series/35612#35612, which is really the same question (but without an explicit representation of the data).  Your dataset looks unusual insofar as the errors occur in blocks and, within each block, appear to be of a constant size. That likely tells you a great deal about the nature of the errors; and, if it's a good hypothesis, suggests some specific solutions that will be more powerful than any generic method.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to CrossValidated!

I would perhaps go iteratively from the beginning to the end, setting all data points to missing where the absolute or relative difference to the last non-missing data point is large. It seems in your dataset, the wrong sensor data is easily discernible by the large jump compared to what you would expect (perhaps allow for increasing differences the further away you move from the last non-missing data point). By setting them iteratively to missing, you will be also able to discern adjacent wrong data point. In a second step you can then interpolate the missing points again iteratively via splines or moving averages.

You can also try some robust regression approaches such as quantile regression (with a flexible trend component).

Comment: Thanks Arne, i'll try your way. About second way, what is quantile regression ?

Comment: Quantile regression estimates conditional quantiles (such as the median) rather than the conditional mean as it is the case for OLS. This has the advantage that quantile regression used to be more robust to outliers in the independent variables. This is why it can be used for outlier detection. Specifying the trend is however not trivial.