# Real-time anomaly detection for online time -series

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection, decomposition, real-time

I am new to the anomaly detection world and am dealing with a project to detect real-time anomalies for a time-series in a fraud detection schema. I read the answer by Rob Hyndman [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/simple-algorithm-for-online-outlier-detection-of-a-generic-time-series) and like the simplicity of it. However, I have to concerns. 1) I read that STL is not scalable for real-time analytics [(see here for example)](https://medium.com/pinterest-engineering/building-a-real-time-anomaly-detection-system-for-time-series-at-pinterest-a833e6856ddd). What is the best decomposition choice here beside fourier. 2) How can I use Rob Hyndman  for a new/real-time event by using this approach? For example, let say we are time  `t` and a new event happens (like a credit card activity). How can I detect if this is an anomaly or not given the dynamic and non-stationary nature of my time-series?

Comment: How do describe credit card activity as a time series? Is it like daily or hourly sum of transactions?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus that is true. Total number of transactions hourly.

Comment: Could you add some more context on the kind of anomaly problem you want to solve? This question seems way too broad otherwise.